# TortoiseSVN freeze after transferring @1 MB data

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, connectivity

I'm using Apache Subversion to manage and store a decent volume of code. Trying to get at it on a standard work machine using svn+ssh with TortoiseSVN on Windows Vista, I find that I can't actually bring all of it down to my local machine at once - the transfer stops after about 1 MB. I can grab it all in fits and starts by canceling the process and updating the incomplete working copy, but that's not the real problem.

The real problem is, trying to merge multiple code branches requires enough data transfer to choke the connection, and as far as I can tell there's no such thing as resuming an incomplete merge.

I have no idea why this is happening - the only resolution steps that have fixed the problem for anyone else on my Google crawl seems to indicate an aggressive antivirus might have something to do with it, but disabling the one that was installed on the work machine (Symantec Endpoint Protection) or ordering it to ignore the destination directory and transfer process doesn't seem to help any.

**Anybody out there seen TortoiseSVN flat-out stop when transferring modest quantities of information, and what can I tweak to fix the problem?**

I'm pretty sure it's not Vista-specific, since my buddy with his Windows XP machine from the last rollout is having exactly the same problem.

A little extra information:

- TortoiseSVN version 1.5.5, 32-bit on a 32-bit version of Vista.
- Connecting to a Solaris 9 box over SSH 1, running Subversion 1.5.3. The version of Solaris and SSH aren't negotiable, since this is a repurposed old server and we manage configurations pretty strictly.
- I've poked around on the Solaris machine and it doesn't look like there are problems at all, aside from the system trying to Kerberos-authenticate me and failing. The process is apparently just waiting for client-side input (in the middle of a checkout?) and Tortoise doesn't seem to be providing the right kind.
- Switching to, say, PLink from TortoisePLink doesn't seem to make any difference - the process begins, but when it stalls out I'm not seeing anything in the terminal window.

Even some help on figuring out what's going wrong here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What server are you connected to? I've had similar problems when running a 32bit windows binary for the server on a 64bit machine. It used to just stop under heavy load, especially when doing merges.

It's possible that a 32/64bit mismatch on the client might also cause the problem, but I've not experienced that particular problem.

Comment: TortoiseSVN is running on a 32-bit version of Vista. The server is a 64-bit Solaris box running version 1.5.3 of Subversion. 

Man, I hope that's not the problem, or this might be varying kinds of impossible to solve.

Comment: It might be worth grabbing a copy of VisualSVN, throwing it on a 32-bit machine and copying the repository over.. might give you an idea if it's an issue with your client or your client connecting to that server.

Comment: Migrating subversion over to a newer linux machine seems to have fixed the problem. I still have no idea what was going wrong in the first place but I'm guessing general cruft + SSH 1 are somehow involved.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.. annoyed the hell out of me when I had the similar problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable TCP Auto-Tuning! It is known to cause problems with TSVN.
[howto disable](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/03/22/disable-tcp-auto-tuning-to-solve-slow-network-cannot-load-web-page-or-download-email-problems-in-vista/)